# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() for np.argmax

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Even tho I'm not evaluating any statement. The error comes up when I'm trying to pass this

```
max_sharpe_idx = np.argmax(results[2])
```

where results is previously passed as

```
results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios), object)
```

and results[2] is an array of floats.

Why is it raising this error, I can't comprehend, any thoughts?
Can provide the whole functions if needed.

EDIT: Function that fills results:

```
def random_portfolios(num_portfolios, mean_returns, cov_matrix, risk_free_rate):
    results = np.zeros((3,num_portfolios), object)
    weights_record = []
    for i in range(num_portfolios):
        weights = np.random.random(12)
        weights /= np.sum(weights)
        weights_record.append(weights)
        portfolio_std_dev, portfolio_return = portfolio_annualised_performance(weights, mean_returns, cov_matrix)
        results[0,i] = portfolio_std_dev
        results[1,i] = portfolio_return
        results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
    return results, weights_record
```

UPDATE: When printing the type of results and results[2,0] this is the output:

```
results: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
results[2,0]: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The variable that is probably raising a problem is:

```
portfolio_return <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The output of portfolio_return looks like this:

```
ABB.ST          0.043190
ALFA.ST         0.015955
AMD             0.031319
SAAB-B.ST       0.018625
ERIC-B.ST       0.080382
FORTUM.HE       0.013456
INVE-B.ST       0.044658
NDA-SE.ST       0.027568
NOKIA-SEK.ST    0.040725
SWED-A.ST       0.013694
TEL2-B.ST       0.038682
VOLV-B.ST       0.003941
dtype: float64
```

Since portfolio return is a an output from:

```
mean_returns = returns.mean()
pandas.core.series.Series
```

How do I get around this?
Full code if needed: https://github.com/timoudas/PortfolioOpt
But the conclusion is that there a underlying data-structure issues that I do not know how to solve

Comment: If result[2] is an array of floats, of what datatype is 'object'? Could you do  give the printout of type(results[2])?

Comment: The type of results[2] is:: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: what about the shape of it ?

Comment: The shape of results is (3,2500), the shape of results[2] should be (1, 2500)

Comment: Depends on what object is. A working example would be nice.

Comment: No problem with: `np.argmax(np.zeros((3,3),object)[2])`

Comment: Given what we know, this seems fine. I wonder there is something wrong when you actually assign/fill up results array. I would suggest you print out shapes of results and results[2] after point of assignment to make sure. Or provide some more details as @emilaz suggested.

Comment: Updated with the function that fills results, please tell me if more info is needed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `results[2]` is not an array of floats, otherwise what you provided would work. If conversion is possible,

```
np.argmax(results[2].astype(float))
```

should do it. If this yields an

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

then I think the reason is that your numpy array not only contains numbers, but also other objects such as strings. Your array originally being of type `object` makes this very likely. I would recommend taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716478/the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any/55716809#55716809) post and also make sure your object definitely contains nothing else than floats/integers.

Comment: Yeah the error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Didn't show up instead it told me:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: What is the output of print(type(results[2][0])) and print(results[2][0])

Comment: FIRST PRINT: <class 'numpy.float64'>
SECOND PRINT: 0.7140668497187416

Comment: Weird. Please add a small working example, meaning a self-contained example which we can try and run ourselves.

Comment: Will try to create one, if you don't want me to create a github repository and post all the code?

Comment: To add a bit of clarity perhaps, the reason why I set results as an object was because I was receiving the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. And by setting it to an object the error didn't show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191942/discussion-between-emilaz-and-misterbutter).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take seriously the error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The problem must be an array element that is a pandas `Series`!

```
In [145]: import pandas as pd                                                   
In [146]: S = pd.Series(np.arange(10))                                          

In [148]: x = np.empty(3,object)                                                
In [150]: x[:]=[S,S,S]                                                          
In [151]: x                                                                     
Out[151]: 
array([0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
....
9    9
dtype: int64], dtype=object)
```

Now I can recreate your error message:

```
In [152]: np.argmax(x)                                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-81bcc042be54> in <module>
----> 1 np.argmax(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in argmax(a, axis, out)
   1101 
   1102     """
-> 1103     return _wrapfunc(a, 'argmax', axis=axis, out=out)
   1104 
   1105 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     54 def _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds):
     55     try:
---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
     57 
     58     # An AttributeError occurs if the object does not have

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1478                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1479                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1480 
   1481     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So you must have an object array that contains one or more `Series`

You give some code, but don't specify the nature (`type`) of the variables:

```
results[2,i] = (portfolio_return - risk_free_rate) / portfolio_std_dev
```

Comment: https://github.com/timoudas/PortfolioOpt/blob/master/Code here you will find all code to recreate everything, please let me now if there is any trouble

Comment: The raw data come from a pandas Dataframe, and is of type float64

Comment: results[2,0] is of type <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: Some place in that `results[2]`array there's a pandas `Series`.  The `sequence` ValueError is further evidence that you are assigning a value like that to `results`.  A Series is a sequence (so is a list and an array).  `argmax` compares elements of the array.  Comparing  a `Series` to another `Series` or even a number will produce this `ambiguity` error.

Comment: Is there a way to find out exactly what produces this error,?

Comment: You are completly right, when printing again this is the results I got:  results: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
results[2,0]: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> How do I solve this?